# HashMap with String Array and integer array value doesnt print the output

Tags: java

i want the value and key of the array to be printed using Hashmap...but i am getting Adress using this.

```
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map.Entry;

import java.util.Set;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

public class ArrayHash

{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        int[] WorkingDay=new int[13];
        int i=0;
        String[] Name=new String[13];       
        String file="C:\\Users\\Dhananjay Kumar\\Empdetail\\Detail.csv";
        HashMap<String[],int[]> hashfunc=new HashMap<String[],int[]>();
        CSVReader reader=new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
        String[] read;
        while((read = reader.readNext()) !=null)
        {
            WorkingDay[i]=Integer.parseInt(read[2]);
             Name[i]=read[0];
             i++;           
        }
        hashfunc.put(Name,WorkingDay);
        hashfunc.get(Name);
        Set<Entry<String[], int[]>> entrySet = hashfunc.entrySet();     
        for (Entry entry : entrySet)
        {
            System.out.println("key: " + entry.getKey() + " value: " + entry.getValue());           
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: its an array.....entry.getValue gives reference of that array not array elements

Comment: can you give a sample entry and how do you expect it to be ?

Comment: You would probably get easier of when mapping the different keys to the same map, or does this give you problems? Or is it really a HashMap<String,Integer> you are looking for?

Comment: i am getting Adress of these values so where i should make change?? @Prasanna Kumar

Comment: yes  i am looking for HashMap<String[],Integer[]> ....i want like each   corresponding value of string array will be the key for each value  of integer array @patrik.

Comment: @dhananjay My point is thatt having an array as a key seems as a design flaw. Also, you seems to look for a single element and not an array. Are you sure you really want an array as key?

Comment: yes i want array as key. @patrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if you are really needing an object of type `HashMap<String,Integer>`. Also, there is a written coding convention in Java which states that the beginning `{` should be at the same line as the declaration of the statement. I am not too found of it either, but since this is convention I follow it.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {    
    String file="C:\\Users\\Dhananjay Kumar\\Empdetail\\Detail.csv";
    HashMap<String,Integer> hashfunc=new HashMap<String,Integer>(); // !!!
    CSVReader reader=new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
    String[] read;
    while((read = reader.readNext()) !=null) {
        haschfunc.put(read[0], Integer.parseInt(read[2])); // !!!
    }   
    for (Entry entry : hashfunc.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("key: " + entry.getKey() + " value: " + entry.getValue());           
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
System.out.println("key: " + entry.getKey() + " value: " + Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

> **`entry.getValue()`** gives reference of that array not array elements

Use **`Arrays.toString((int[]) entry.getValue())`** so that it will print values.
or use a for loop to array length and print each value

```
     for(Entry entry : entrySet) {
        int[] arrInt = (int[]) entry.getValue();
        String[] arrString = (String[]) entry.getKey();
        for(int j=0; j<arrInt.length; j++){
            System.out.println(arrInt[j]);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hashfunc
```

is holding the array reference as key hence its printing the address.

```
for (Entry entry : entrySet)
    {
        System.out.println("key: " + entry.getKey() + " value: " + entry.getValue()); 
       String[] names=entry.getKey();
       for(String name:names){
         System.out.println(name);
       }
       int[] workingDays=entry.getValue();
       for(int workingDay:workingDays){
         System.out.println(workingDay);
       } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to print the entire array for the value of each entry in entrySet.

The default toString() method of an Array just returns the address of the object. Therefore you need to use another method, such as`Arrays.toString(entry.getValue())` , or create your own method to print the array in the format you require.